# Euler Project - Greatest prime factor computational power can't handle my script

Tags: c, for-loop, prime-factoring

I have this working bit of code but it just hangs when i apply big numbers to it.
Essentially I'm working out the greatest prime factor.
It's computationally expensive because of the size of the prime I'm trying to find (eulers project)
My weenie little laptop cannot handle this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* My code is done on the assumption i do not get garbage in. */
bool isPrime(long long int num){
    int val;
    for (val = 3; val < num; val=val+2) { //Offset at 3 start then +2 to half calculations required such that 
                                      //I don't waste processing power on even numbers.
                                      //I'd like to know if i could also skip the calculation by avoiding multiples of 3
    if (num % val == 0) { 
        return false; //Exit this function when remainder is 0, such that number is divisible by 
        }  
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    long long int num_in=600851475143; //This does not work.
    // long long int num_in=13195; //This works
    long long i;
    // The biggest factor = total/2. 
    // However what is the biggest prime factor?

    for (i = num_in/2; i > 1; i=i-2)
    {
        if (num_in % i == 0) //Confirm this is a factor
        {
            if (isPrime(i))  //Confirm that factor is prime
            {
                printf("%lld \n", i );
                return 0; // Exit program

            }
        }
    }
    printf("This has been a failure \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a question you have? Or a specific help you seek?

Comment: May I suggest you change your algorithm? Just keep on dividing by the smallest found factor until you can no longer divide :) You'll see your program improve its speed millions of times.

Comment: The point of Project Euler problems is to come up with something more efficient than brute force algorithms.  It has nothing to do with "your weenie little laptop."  Your laptop has more than enough computational power to solve the problem when using a more efficient algorithm, and the world's largest supercomputers don't have enough when using an inefficient enough algorithm.

Comment: @YePhIcK Good suggestion but should be noted that speed increase depends on input. In case of prime input it won't change

Comment: Another problem might be that your `long long`, despite being 64-bit, is being assigned a constant of type `int`, which causes all sorts of havoc when `sizeof(int) != sizeof(long long)`. Looking at `600851475143`, it should be `600851475143LL`. Otherwise you will in the best case get a number modulo `2^(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int) - 1)`, which is 1703537351 in the case of a 32-bit `int`. It has nothing to do with your algorithm, but it is worth noting for when you get your algorithm to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on my suggestion in a comment - re-work your algorithm to reduce the amount of number crunching:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    const long long int num_in = 600851475143;
    long long int curr = num_in;
    while(true){
        const long long int sr = static_cast<long long int>(sqrt(static_cast<long double>(curr)));
        long long int i = 2;
        for(; i <= sr; ++i){
            if(curr % i == 0){
                curr /= i;  // get rid of this prime
                break;      // and start the loop again
            }
        }
        if(i >= sr){
            // couldn't divide anymore
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << num_in << "'s largestprime factor is: " << curr << std::endl;
}
```

The code above outputs:

```
600851475143's largestprime factor is: 6857
```

Note, that you can use good-old `C`-style typecasting to shorten the long line with the `sqrt()` call in it, like so:

```
const long long int sr = (long long int)sqrt((long double)curr);
```

Answer (score 1):

To find whether a number is prime it's enough to check if it has divisors up to square root of the number (mathematical proof is almost trivial). Similar logic holds when you check if a number is a factor - so no need to check beyond square root of the number. These are the most important slow downs of your computation.